# PHP's PDO query not executing when LIMIT is too high?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the weirdest PHP PDO problem, and I hope you guys can sort it out for me.

If I set `$checkLimit` to 50000, the query works fine. However, if I set it to anything above 50k, it doesn't return any results - and it doesn't cast any error messages either (I've already turned them on using `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING)`.

```
$sql = "
   SELECT d_domain_name AS domainName, d_domain_id AS domainID
   FROM domains
   ORDER BY d_domain_name_length ASC, d_domain_name ASC
   LIMIT :checkLimit
";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':checkLimit', intval($checkLimit), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $result) {
 // 50k moments of magic
}
```

If I run the query outside of PHP, it works with any limit (even 500k, takes about 3 minutes).

I've tried changing `$results = $stmt->fetchAll()` to `while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {}` in order to try and save memory, but that didn't do anything, unfortunately.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? What am I missing? Why can't I go over 50k?

Comment: Take into consideration `int` values are not infinite, you may have got a over the limit number.

Comment: It doesn't what?  Don't leave us in suspense!

Comment: @fedorqui: 50,000 would fit VERY comfortably into a 32bit PHP int

Comment: check php and/or apache logs. You may have run out of memory

Comment: @Populus: Query worked fine back when I was using mysql_query().

Comment: @MadMarvin well I'm not sure about the memory usage differences between PDO and mysql extension, but there could be enough different that builds up over 50k rows. It may also be worth tweaking the settings in MySQL temporarily.

Comment: I had a [runaway memory issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56347) with MySQL recently whereby if I had an ORDER BY (no matter what LIMIT) in the query, I could literally SSH in and watch the `/tmp` directory disk allocation churn from ~24mb to peg at ~480mb about 5-7 seconds after initializing the query, all in a methodical 20 seconds or so. You need to learn how to use PDO to get the best results; it's not `mysql_*`.

Comment: So setting it to exactly 50001 doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

PDO uses "buffered query" by default.

> This means that query results are immediately transferred from the
>   MySQL Server to PHP in is then kept in the memory of the PHP process.
>   .... The downside of the buffered mode is that larger result
>   sets might require quite a lot memory. ....
>
> Following these characteristics buffered queries should be used in
>   cases where you expect only a limited result set or need to know the
>   amount of returned rows before reading all rows. Unbuffered mode
>   should be used when you expect larger results.

50k is a large result set. Could you try to **let pdo use unbuffered mode** and **fetch one row at a time**? This is the example copied from the reference. The 2nd line sets the unbuffered mode.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world", 'my_user', 'my_pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$uresult = $pdo->query("SELECT Name FROM City");
if ($uresult) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: It works great - except that I can't execute new queries inside the query; `Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.`

Comment: Could you try open another pdo connection to the same databasse for other buffered queries?

Comment: @ChuanMa - Sorry for answering 4 years later, but yes, if I just opened a second PDO connection I could execute new queries. Still use this method, thanks for the answer. :)